# how to load http url with instantApp webview?

Tags: android, http, android-instant-apps

I'm trying to make an **instantApp** and put a webView at the opening activity.
When I add a url starts with https I can see the website on my webview.
but when the url starts with http, I get an error:

> net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED

Here is my code:

```
public class HelloActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello);

    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());


    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

    webView.loadUrl("http://www.foxnews.com/");

    // webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com"); this url is working


  }
}
```

Hope you can help me with that.

Comment: Why you do not want to use the one with `https`?

Comment: Because Android Instant Apps do not support http websites.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With reference to android [Instant-App Document](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/faqs.html)

All the network traffic from inside instant apps must use **`HTTPS`**. Instant apps does ***`not support HTTP`***.